# Installing Docxfactory in python

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to install the package `Docxfactory` to use in `python`.  I am pretty new to python and I have had about 50/50 success with installing packages...  For this one when I use pip as in pip install docxfactory it says

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement DocxFactory from      versions: ) No matching distribution found for DocxFactory"
```

So I read the tutorial on how to install it and they said to first download `DocxFactoryWin64.zip` from [www.docxfactory.com](http://www.docxfactory.com) and put it in the program files directory.  So I did that.  I added the system variable and then it said to go to the docxfactory/python folder and type:

```
python setup.py install
```

I had some earlier issues I fixed by downloading Visual C++ Express.  I get this:

```
> Output

WordProcessingCompiler.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__df
wc_compile
WordProcessingCompiler.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__df
wc_setTempDir
...
build\lib.win32-3.5\_docxfactory.cp35-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 50 unreso
lved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\
link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

I have Python 3.5.1 Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in case anyone else has this issue.  There are two versions of the Docxfactory a 32 bit and a 64 bit, I downloaded the 64 bit version since that would apply to me.  The problem was I had a 32 bit python installed.  So that is why it would not compile correctly.  Once I got the 64 bit python version it was just fine.